# Invalid String Literal with base 10

Tags: python-2.7, int

I am having trouble figuring out why i'm getting the ValueError 'Invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'addin.txt'

```
out = open('addout.txt', 'w')

for line in open(int('addin.txt')):
    line = line.strip()
out.write((line [0] + line[1]) + (line [3] + line [4]))
out.close
```

Comment: Uh, why are you parsing the string `addin.txt` as an int? That isn't going to work.

Comment: I'm a bit of noob at python I am trying to create a program that will read two integers on the same line separated by a single whitespace

Comment: And then are you trying to write their sum into addout.txt?

Comment: I don't know I am having trouble converting the string in the input file to an integer. I forgot to say that I need to find the sum of the two integers and write them to addout.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the corrected version of your code, with some comments that I hope you'll find useful.

```
# open the file in as writable
out = open('addout.txt', 'w')

# go through each line of the input text
for line in open('addin.txt'):
    # split into parts (will return two strings if there are two parts)
    # this is syntax sugar for:
    #   parts = line.split()
    #   l = parts[0]
    #   r = parts[1]
    l,r = line.split()

    # parse each into a number and add them together
    sum = int(l) + int(r)

    # write out the result as a string, not forgetting the new line
    out.write(str(sum)+"\n")

# clean up your file handle
out.close()
```

The core bit is `int(somestring)`. Read [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#int). If you needed to specify a different base, it would look something like `int(somestring, base=8)`.

I hope this helps.